# How to enable Alternative Layout in the frontend editing

Tags: front-end, editor, editing

I'm trying to enable user to choose article alternative layout in the article frontpage editing form. 
I add this code below to *[root]/templates/protostar/html/com_content/form/edit.php*

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('article_layout','attribs'); ?>
```

But it shows nothing in the frontend editing form. Any idea how to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem to be easily possible, currently:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/7809